# d3 updating multiple svgs

Tags: svg, d3.js

I successfully create multiple (2) svgs on my page and I am trying to update them.

```
$('#Records li a ').click(function() {


        var id =  event.target.id;
        var idparts = id.split("_");
        var numrec =  idparts[1];

        $.get('php/connection2.php', { numrecs: numrec}, function(data) {

            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
        var numericArray = createdata(obj);
        var length = numericArray.length;
        var svgs = d3.selectAll('svg');
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            svgs[0][i].attr("_data_",numericArray[i]);
        }
        return false;


    });
    });
```

I know this isnt correct:

```
svgs[0][i].attr("_data_",numericArray[i]);
```

Attached is a SS as we are entering the for loop

[image]

EDIT:this is part of a loop to create EACH svg.

```
var svg = d3.select("#content").append("div").attr("class","datadiv").attr("id",mydata[i]+"_div").style("float","left").selectAll("svg")
                .data(thisdata)
                .enter().append("svg")
                .attr("class", "box")
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.bottom + margin.top)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
                .call(chart)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `.data(function(d, i) { return numericArray[i]; })`?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<SVGSVGElement> has no method 'data'

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do? Is all you want to update the data?

Comment: Yes, Thats all. I showed the Object Hierarchy thinking it might help.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff's answer is correct - you just need to rebind the new data. `.data()` is a method of a d3 selection, not of an SVG DOM element. In all likelihood, you just want `d3.selectAll('svg').data(numericArray)`, instead of your `for` loop.

Comment: Yes...this sort of worked . the _data_ is updated but the graph doenst show the changes. I tried .enter and .enter().append('svg'). Also an official answer from @LarsKotthoff so I can UpVote is needed.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're trying to do. Maybe you could post a complete example? After passing in the new data, you still need to operate on the update selection in the usual D3 way.

Comment: Thanks Lars. I really appreciate this. http://ampsoft.com/V/data.php

Comment: In case you are wondering I created seperate svg's because the range of data can be up to 100 fold from one box to another and I wanted the height of each one the same. I've updated the code (online) and still looking for the correct way to do the updating.Thanks